# Knex version is not compatible with jest

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, jestjs, knex.js, supertest

I don't know whether the title of this question is expressed correctly or not. I'm having a weird issue. Issue is regarding api and unit testing.

I can't conclude what is the issue specifically, the api is running perfectly, but when i run unit testing, it will return error.

This is the error i'm having

```
[ERROR] dashboard - Error:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'raw')
at listCustomers (discovery-dashboard\controllers\customer.js:80:39)
    at handler (discovery-dashboard\api\v1\customers.js:22:29)
    at discovery-dashboard\middlewares\async.js:12:11
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (discovery-dashboard\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (discovery-dashboard\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at handler (discovery-dashboard\middlewares\validate.js:22:7)
    at discovery-dashboard\middlewares\async.js:12:11
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (discovery-dashboard\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (discovery-dashboard\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at discovery-dashboard\middlewares\authorize.js:59:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Here is the code of unit tests

```
test("can be listed", async () => {
  const response = await request.get("/api/v1/customers").set("Authorization", authHeader);

  expect(response.status).toBe(200);
  expect(response.body).toEqual({ value: accountsList, totalCount: 6 });
});
```

This is the code of controller which actually have **raw** function to execute the raw MsSQL query.

```
let query = `
      SELECT Id, Email, ExpireDate, Name, Username, Credit, SafeLimit, TotalCredits,
          CreatedOn, IsEnterprise, HLRFees, HLRConsumption, MNPFees, MNPConsumption, hlrconsumptiondl, MNPConsumptiondl, rownumber
      FROM  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS rownumber,*
  FROM Accounts ${queryFilters}) as somex`;

  let pagination = '';

  if (options.offset || options.limit) pagination = ' WHERE';
  if (options.offset && !options.limit) pagination += ` rownumber > ${options.offset}`;
  if (!options.offset && options.limit) pagination += ` rownumber <= ${options.limit}`;
  if (options.offset && options.limit) pagination += ` rownumber > ${options.offset} AND rownumber <= ${options.offset + options.limit}`;

  let customers = await SQLConnection.raw(query + pagination);
```

This is the connection details for MsSQL.

```
const connection =
  /** @type Knex */
  (config.env == "test"
    ? null
    : /* istanbul ignore next */
      Knex({
        client: "mssql",
        connection: {
          host: config.mssql.host,
          database: config.mssql.database,
          user: config.mssql.username,
          password: config.mssql.password,
        },
        log: logger,
      }));

const mssql = { connection };
```

Can we create new mock connection for MSSQL knex, similarly as we use redis-mock and mongo-memory-server for unit testing?

I think this is the error maybe, kindly correct me if this is not the issue of creating mock connection.